# adding numbers inside a text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macbook

I have cells containing number and text and I would like to sum only the numbers at the end of the cells.
here is an example of my cells :

L4-R4

L8-R9

L11-R11

L12-R11

L12-R11

L9-R9

the answer would be: L56-R55

after that, I would like to update the answer also on another sheet. 
let's say my cells are on F80 to F89 on sheet1, then the answer is on F90 on the same sheet (sheet1).
now I want the answer(F90) be also updated on the sheet 2 on for example B1. 
How can I do these on Mac computer?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Helper Columns

The fastest way to approach problems like this is often to use helper columns to break the problem down.  To do math on the numerical portions, I extracted the numbers.

[image]

You can get the locations of everything from the position of the `R`.  In column B, I extracted the L number.  B1:

```
=MID(A1,2,FIND("R",A1)-3)*1
```

MID extracts the characters starting with the second, for a length of the R position minus 3 (i.e., minus the `L`, `-`, and `R`).  That is extracted as a string, so multiplying by `1` turns it into a number.

The R number is in column C.  C1:

```
 =MID(A1,FIND("R",A1)+1,LEN(A1))*1
```

In this case, MID starts at the position after the R, and takes the rest of the string.  The number of characters is specified as the entire length of the A1 value, but Excel runs out of characters when it comes to the end of the string.

An alternate way to get the R number is the approach used in Rajesh S's answer:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("R",A1),"")*1
```

This replaces all of the characters to the left of the number, from the first through the `R`, with nothing.  Again, the `*1` converts the result to a numerical value.

The result in A8 is generated by building the new string using `&` to concatenate the pieces, plugging in the helper column sums:

```
="L" & SUM(B1:B6) & "-R" & SUM(C1:C6)
```

You can hide the helper columns or stick them out of the way if you don't want them visible.

#### Without helper columns

Once you've figured out how to do it with helper columns, you can often eliminate the helper columns by using the formula in an array-style calculation.  SUMPRODUCT lets you do that with a regular formula; it calculates the result for each value in the range, then sums them up.  The sum of the L values can be done directly with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A6,2,FIND("R",A1:A6)-3)))
```

This is the same formula used for the helper column, but the single cell reference is replaced with the data range.  This also illustrates another method for converting the text result to a number; Instead of `*1`, it uses a double negative to treat the result as a number while leaving its sign unchanged.

Similarly, for the R number, I'll use the alternate formula because it's a little shorter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(REPLACE(A1:A6,1,FIND("R",A1:A6),"")))
```

Those formulas give you the sums without needing the helper columns.  You can build the final result in a single cell by using these sums instead of the `SUM(B1:B6)` and `SUM(C1:C6)` that used the helper column results:

```
="L" & SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A6,2,FIND("R",A1:A6)-3))) & "-R" & SUMPRODUCT(--(REPLACE(A1:A6,1,FIND("R",A1:A6),"")))
```

#### Dynamic answer on another sheet

To have an automatically updated result replicated on another sheet, just put, in that display cell, a reference to the original result.  You include the sheet name in the cell reference, connected by an exclamation mark.  To refer to the result in cell A8 of Sheet1, the cell reference would be `=Sheet1!A8`.

A fast way to create the cell reference is to type `=` in the display cell, then before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, go to the first sheet and click on the result cell.  Excel will fill in the cell reference for you.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much for this amazing formula!!!!

Answer (score 0):

*To solve the issue you need value in Helper Column:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `B90`:

`=LEFT(A90,FIND("-",A90)-1)`

- Formula in Cell `C90`:

`=REPLACE(A90,1,FIND("-",A90),"")`

*Fill both formula down.*

- Enter this array formula in Cell `B96`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

`{=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(B90:B95,"L",""),B90:B95)}`

- An array formula in cell `C96`, finish this also with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

`{=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(C90:C95,"R",""),C90:C95)}`

- Final formula in Cell `D96`:

`="L"&B96&"-"&"R"&C96`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I started playing with array formulas to see if this could be done without helper columns, but it made my brain hurt.  Did you look at trying to build the helper cell formulas into the array formulas?  That could get you to a one cell solution.

Comment: @fixer1234,, let me try.

Comment: @fixer1234, any single formula can't do this since has two different alphabets!

Comment: Were you able to get the row 96 values without the helper cells?

Comment: @fixer1234, not giving correct result.

Comment: I got yours into a single array formula: `="L"&SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1:A6,FIND("-",A1:A6)-1),"L",""))&"-R"&SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1:A6,1,FIND("-",A1:A6),""),"R",""))`.  (Note: my ranges are different.)  It works in WPS Office but can't test it in Excel.  If you can verify that it works, you're welcome to run with it.  In your array formulas, I couldn't figure out your repeat of the ranges at the end, but they don't appear to be required.  You could use the existing answer to explain the logic, then combine it to the single formula at the end without the need for helper cells.

Comment: Even better, use SUMPRODUCT to avoid the array formula: `="L"&SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1:A6,FIND("-",A1:A6)-1),"L",""))&"-R"&SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1:A6,1,FIND("-",A1:A6),""),"R",""))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96994/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).

Comment: @RajeshS: thank you very much for you answer and for your help and all those chats.